# The "Send" function in AutoIt does nothing, no matter the input

Tags: windows-10, autoit

We're trying to automate some stuff with AutoIt, but we're having an issue with the `Send` function. No matter what we give it, the function does nothing. `Send("Foo bar")` does nothing, `Send("^a")` does nothing, etc.

Using `ControlSend("", "", "", "Hello")` does work, but we lose capital letters. All text is lower case. Additionally, stuff like `"^a"` doesn't work, and we have to use `"{CTRLDOWN}a{CTRLUP}"`, which is a pain.

We have tried Googling why the `Send` function won't work, but in all cases we just find that the person in question had some kind of "wait" function call before it that never returned. We can't find any cases where the function `Send` is definitely called, but just does nothing.

Adding `#RequireAdmin` to the top of the file didn't help.

---

We're using a fully updated current version of Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Try this which works well for me, first ensure the window you need to select all files, etc. in is activated with **`WinActivate("<Title>")`**, then on the next line put **`Sleep(500)`**, and then on the next line put **`Send("^a")`** this should work fine. You may need to post some of your logic that is necessary for others to test if this doesn't work for you. If you do still have problems, post the bare minimum code needed to replicate your problem and I'll give it a test run if so.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @William Sorry, I think I gave up

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. It's the same in both AutoIt2 and AutoIt3. WinActivate does work to activate the window, but then no keys can be sent and no mouse clicks work either. I also tried compiling and running the exe as Administrator, it still behaves the same way. I turned UAC off in Windows, it still behaves the same way. No one knows the answer.